# Anyone have the C5 Collections 2.0 Documentation

Tags: c#, collections, documentation, chm

Ive been trying for an hour to install all the files that GitHub says I need to compile the documentation for the C5 Collections 2.0 and I'm still having no luck with it. I've also googled for at least another 2 hours with no luck. I have no idea why they didn't just compile it themselves.

Does anybody have the compiled .chm for this? It would help me tremendously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation from GitHub is compiled by the NuDoq website and available here:
http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Projects/C5

This is the first time I heard of NuDoq. I don't know how long they will be around. It is a cool initiative though.

Comment: Sweet that is handy. This is exactly what I had wanted. Lol, shame it took so long to find. Guess I'm ahead of my time :) I went ahead and changed your answer to the correct one as yours address the latest version and is closer to the version I had requested originally. Even better that it's the latest version actually. Thanks for finding this.

Answer (score 1):

[There is a document describing the changes and rationale](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/c5-rasmus-nielsen-2011-05-25.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Sweet Jiminy, this was bothering me too. I know this question was asked ages ago but here's the answer.

http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1.1/c5doc/frames.htm

Comment: I had requested the docs for the 2.0 version (2011) and this links to the docs for the 1.1.1 version (2010) which is basically the 1.1.0 version (2008). However since it's going on nearly 3 years and nobody else has bothered to answer or compile these I'll give you the credit. It is helpful and something I hadn't previously found so I do appreciate you stopping in to toss the link my way :)

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, version 2.4 of the docs can be found here:

https://c5docs.azurewebsites.net/class_c5_1_1_tree_bag.html

Found this link on the C5 github website:

https://github.com/sestoft/C5

It looks like they finally got their act together with respect to providing pre-built documentation.